# jquery selector for finding div with empty inner html directly inside a parent div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a div structure as show in code below. There could be multiple parent divs with ids of p0, p1, p2 etc. I am trying to find child divs  directly under a div having an id that starts with `p`. I need to find empty child divs separately from non-empty child divs.

When I run the code below, then the method `getEmptyDivs` return 0 elements, whereas, the method `getNonEmptyDivs` returns 12 elements that includes all child empty as well as non-empty divs.

Demo for this question is at following URL: [demo code sample](http://js.do/sun21170/77924)

**Sample code that does not return correct number of elements**

```
<div id='p0'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
    </div>
    <div id='p1'>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>some content</div>
     <div>some content</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getEmptyDivs(); alert(x.length);">Get Empty Divs</button>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getNonEmptyDivs(); alert(x.length);">Get Non-Empty Divs</button>
<script>
function getEmptyDivs() { 
   return $("div[id^='p'] > div[innerHTML='']");
}
function getNonEmptyDivs() { 
   return $("div[id^='p'] > div[innerHTML!='']");
}
</script>
```

I have tried the above code but it returns incorrect number of elements.

**Question** : What selector can I use to get a list of all empty div elements directly under divs that have their id starting with `p`, and also the selector for getting similar non-empty divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` and `:not(:empty)` selectors:

```
function getEmptyDivs() {
    return $("div[id^='p'] > div:empty");
}

function getNonEmptyDivs() {
    return $("div[id^='p'] > div:not(:empty)");
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cp8ynnh1/)

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: That was ready-to-go code and it worked without any modifications. Great. Thanks.

Comment: So  `:empty` means `innerHTML is empty`?

Comment: Not just `innerHTML`. From the documentation: `Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).`

Comment: Ok. Get it. Thanks. jquery is too powerful.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Man, you are too fast. LoL. `:)`

Comment: My original functions should have worked according to this URL: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/. But don't know why they did not.

Comment: I think because `innerHtml` is not an attribute.

Comment: That's right, the selector you were using is for attributes on the DOM element, `innerHTML` is a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child selector and filter out with empty stuff:

```
$("#p0 > div").filter(function () {
  return $(this).is(":empty");
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
function getEmptyDivs() { 
  return $("div[id^='p'] > div:empty");
}
function getNonEmptyDivs() { 
  return $("div[id^='p'] > div:not(:empty)");
}
```

```html
<div id='p0'>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
<div id='p1'>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div></div>
  <div>some content</div>
  <div>some content</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getEmptyDivs(); alert(x.length);">Get Empty Divs</button>
<button type="button" onclick="var x =  getNonEmptyDivs(); alert(x.length);">Get Non-Empty Divs</button>
```